# Calling External Functions Once PayPal Approve / Finish the Transaction

Tags: node.js, angular, paypal

I'm integrating PayPal Smart Button for My CheckOut Process Below is the Code to Render the Button

```
     LoadPaypalButton(orderid :string , link : string,token : string , applicationbaseurl:string)
  {
    this.addPaypalScript().then(()=>{paypal.Buttons({enableStandardCardFields: true,
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'blue',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
    },
      createOrder: function() {
        return orderid
       },
       onApprove : function(data , actions) {
        return fetch(link, {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': token,
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            OrderID: data.orderID
          })
        }).then(function(res) {
          return res.json();
        }).then(function(details) {
          console.log( details);
          console.log(details);
          actions.redirect(applicationbaseurl+'OrderHistory/'+token);

        })
       }
     }
    ).render('#paypal-button-container')});


  }
```

Everything Working fine and i want to call external function to handle my UI after transaction finish without taking user to any other page.How can call function like below within the  script

```
callsuccess()
 {
   // Some Other work....
   console.log("Something ..!");

 }
```

I'm Using Angular 8.0 as my front end.this is what i tried so far in OnApprove:

```
   onApprove : function(data , actions) {
    return fetch(link, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        OrderID: data.orderID
      })
    }).then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(details) {

      this.callsuccess(); //  This does not work
      actions.redirect(applicationbaseurl+'OrderHistory/'+token);

    })
   }
```

giving me below error

```
zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callsuccess' of undefined
at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1430:30
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3365:26)
at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3130:43)
at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3861:36
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3397:31)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3174:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3565:35)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion to make this happen ..?

Comment: Change all functions to fat arrows: `function (arg) {` to `(arg) => {`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an arrow function:

```
onApprove : (data , actions) => {
    return fetch(link, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        OrderID: data.orderID
      })
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((details) => {

      this.callsuccess(details);


   actions.redirect(applicationbaseurl+'OrderHistory/'+token);

    })
   }
```

Note how `function(data , actions) {` becomes `(data, actions) => {` and the same goes for the `then` functions of the promises.

This should preserve the `this` as arrow functions have lexical scoping of `this` keyword. This functions are also called `lambda functions`.

Comment: Nope.It Didn't work..! thanks . i Found this on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090296/how-to-call-external-javascript-function-from-inside-onauthorize-paypal-smart-pa             do you have any idea how to translate this in to angular. i never used window object at all

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the `then` functions, they should be arrow functions. I've updated the answer. It should work now.

Comment: still the same it giving me below errors

Comment: Cannot find name 'data'    /   function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>
':' expected.ts(1005) .  / Property 'callsuccess' does not exist on type 'PaypalComponent'

Comment: Well, now the `this` is preserved, you just need to implement the `callsuccess()` method on your PaypalComponent with the code to execute on success

Comment: yes. but i need to access to my other variables within the angular component.seems like i have to define call success function as a window function. like it saying here. but i'm still trying to understand how this will apply for my scenario https://stribny.name/blog/2018/01/how-to-communicate-with-angular-components-outside-angular

Comment: You can pass the info you need to `callsuccess` method. It might be the info you receive as `details`. Try calling `this.callsuccess(details);` and defining the callsuccess(details) method in your PaypalComponent. Log in the console what you receive and check if it's what you need

Comment: Actually Just realize i didn't remove function from function (data,action) part.found after 2 days after did several research . Your answer is the right answer and i just wasted several days because of the mistake

Comment: Thanks @jeprubio it Works for me you save my 1 headache teblet.